# Get close points (geometry) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I have a MySQL database table with a series of points, which is a specific `geometry` data type (basically, a lat/lon coordinate). I need to get all the points that are close to some coordinates (close meaning to less that 1 km, let's say).

Now I am getting ALL points from the table and, from PHP, calculating which of them have a distance shorter than the desired distance (1 km).

The problem is that there a thousands of points, so the performance is very poor.

Is there a way to get only those close points directly from the database? I don't guess what function may help me.

Thank you!

Comment: This discusses 5 ways, starting with the inefficient one you have:  [_Find Nearest_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

Comment: @RickJames doing it client side is even worse than any of the ways there.  If there are only thousands of points a no index approach may be fine.

Comment: @ysth - True.  My 5 ways are all on the server side.  (The first one is really not a contender -- no index, just brute force.)

Comment: Definitely, doing that on the client side is definitely the worst solution. If I tell you that I started by iterating the whole database, and then iterated again to get the closest points of each, you will find out how much I laughed when I discovered that even the bounding box is much more than I expected, compared to a kind of "no-index to the square"... and on the client side. Thanks to @RickJames for such a good explanation for newbies like me.